# How do I create one extended partition and move the whole OS there

Tags: linux, arch-linux, partition, software-installation, kali-linux

The problem is that I have Arch Linux installed on my PC that is pretty old and uses MBR,

I have 4 partitions, look at this picture. I want to install Kali Linux to hack my dog, but cannot create a new partition. It because you cannot have more than 4 partitions on MBR, if I am not mistaken.

I was thinking what if I fist backup `/home` and then delete it, after that I want to create a new extended partition and inside of that I want to create a new `/home` + Kali Linux paritions. But I'm new to linux and don't know how to backup and do the stuff, can anybody step by step explain how to solve my problem?

The other thing was to just create one primary extended partition and move everything there Arch + new Kali linux .
What are some ideas?

[image]

Comment: Do you really, really need that swap partition? Even if you do, you could always use swap files.

Isn't 64GB for / a bit excessive for your needs?

LVM would give you many logical volumes inside a single partition.

Comment: Remove swap and create an extended partition. No backup required. You will lose the 4GB, which is probably acceptable. Regarding your request for help with backups, this site is not very good for step by step tutorials, but there are plenty on the internet. Other suggestion: Add the allocated space to sda4 and run Kali in a virtual machine. Finally a remark: In my opinion, somebody new to Linux should neither use Arch nor Kali.